# Does a multivariate series expansion exist for this function?

Tags: sequences-and-series, taylor-expansion, laurent-series

I have the following function that I was hoping to simplify in some way

$$\displaystyle f(x,y)=\frac{1+x}{1+y+\sqrt{(1-y)^2+y(1-\frac{1}{x})^2}}$$

defined for $0 < {x,y} \leq 1$ and was wondering whether a convergent multivariate expansion existed over the domain of interest.

Thanks, Tom Waits.

Comment: I believe so, as the function is a composition of analytic functions that are nowhere zero in your domain. Have you tried the multivariate Taylor series?

Comment: In such expressions alway try to multiply numerator and denominator by the **conjugate expression of the denominator** : in many cases, it gives you a more manageable expression.